Linking CSS and JS to a HTML page using Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot application and Docker
I'm trying to do a quite simple thing: adding a stylesheet .css file and a .js file to my html page called: "scalata.html" but everytime I get these errors:
GET https://my-domain.app/css/scalata.css 404 (Not Found)
GET https://my-domain.app/js/scalata.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
First of all, in my pom.xml file, I have added these lines in order to correctly setup ThymeLeaf into my Spring Boot project and the Spring-Boot ResourceLocations:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

And this is my complete pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>2.7.0</version>
         <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.groom</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-class</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-class</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--<springsecurity.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version-->
    </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20230227</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.30</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>

This is my "scalata.html":
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--Adding Thymeleaf-->
<html lang ="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!--Enabling proper responsive behavior-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>My Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="../static/css/scalata.css" th:href="@{/css/scalata.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../static/js/scalata.js" th:src="@{/js/scalata.js}">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
    

EDIT:
This is my folder structure:
\---src
    +---main
        +---java  
        +---resources  
            +---jquery  
            +---static  
                +---css  
                    -scalata.css  
                +---js  
                    -scalata.js  
            +---templates
                -scalata.html

Could you help me?
I tried this: Where to put static files such as CSS in a spring-boot project? and this: Linking CSS to HTML view using Thymeleaf

Where are your css and js files located in your project?

@LeeGreiner My .css and .js files are in two separate directory, named, respectively: css and js under the static directory;                                                                                                            1 Project\applicazione\my-class\src\main\resources\static\js\scalata.js                                    2 Project\applicazione\my-class\src\main\resources\static\css\scalata.css                            3 Project\applicazione\my-class\src\main\resources\templates\scalata.html

Locations are correct and you have both web and Thymeleaf starters in your pom which are required. Are you running locally or deploying to a server? I ask because you mentioned my-domain.app in your 404 links. FYI, you have an extra </script> tag before  your </head> tag but this shouldn't contribute to your issue.

Ty for the reply, I'm using ngrok and Docker containers; I have copied and paste an extra </script> only here,  there isn't in my actual html page

If you run the application locally, without Docker and ngrok, do you get the 404 errors?

Yep, I still got: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not scalata.css Found)and Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not scalata.js Found)

Are you using the @EnableWebMvc annotation? If so, you disable Spring's web autoconfiguration and will have to create a class that extends WebMvcConfigurer  and add the css and js resource handlers manually.

Also, do you have a @Controller class defined? If not, Spring web autoconfiguration is not run.

@LeeGreiner thank u a lot for trying to solve my problem.

After days and days of searching, I finally found the solution to my problem.
I forgot to mention that my application uses a proxy (ui_gateaway) and this is the default.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    #timeout attesa back end
    proxy_read_timeout 6000s;

    client_max_body_size 5M;
    client_body_timeout 600s;

    location = / {
        return 301 /login;
    }

    error_page 500 /error.html;
    
    location ~ ^/(scalata|pageA|pagaB|t1) {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://my-class-controller-1:8080;
    }

    location ^~ /api {
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://api_gateway-gateway-1:8090;
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}

The proxy takes care of routing requests to different endpoints but the GET at the /css/scalata.css and at /js/scalata.js endpoints were not redirected so I resolved in this way:

